# Recurrence for number of tile sequences of length n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion

We are placing tiles of colors red,blue and green in a row. Find a recurrence for number of tile sequences of length n (assuming unlimited supply is given) if

a) No further conditions

b) red tiles cannot be adjacent

c) after 2 adjacent red tiles there has to be a blue tile

d) red and green tiles cannot be adjacent

e) the row must contain a blue or a red tile.

Try:
I got a) and b)

Need help on c,d and e

Comment: it's $3n$ for a) , since for each additional tile, there are three possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned in the question but I got part a)

Comment: Some hints. Case a) To any $n$-tile sequence you can append either R, G or B tile. $S(n+1) = 3\cdot S(n).$ Case b) The $n$-tile sequence can end with R or with G or B. If it's R you can append only G or B, if not you can append any color: $S(n)=S_r(n)+S_{g,b}(n), S_{g,b}(n+1) = S(n), S_r(n+1)=S_{g,b}(n)$.

Comment: as for b) - for n=1, 3 sequences. for n=2, 8, since we cannot have adjacent reds. for n=3, 22. notice that there will always be n-1 red tile ending sequences for n; thus the formula in b) is $3^n - 2n + 1$.

Comment: for c, if n=1, then 3. if n=2, then 9. if n=3, then there is one case where there is a double red, so $3^n - 2$ . if n=4, we now have two new cases of double-red - so $3^n - 6 - 4$. you can extrapolate from here.

Comment: the only remaining case that cannot be solved with a variation of my previous work is the case e) ; in this case, consider that all combinations are possible except the row of all green tiles.

Comment: For part d, do you mean red tiles cannot be adjacent to green tiles or a tile that is red or green cannot be adjacent to another tile that is red or green?

Comment: A red tile cannot be adjacent to a green tile and vice versa

Comment: Need Help for last 3 parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part e , we have to consider only one case when there is no blue or green tile that is when all the tiles are red and that would be $3^{n}-1$. So, we can assume $a(n) = 3^{n}-1$ and we can continue to find $a(n-1)$ to find the relation between $a(n)$ and $a(n-1) $.

For part c,We have three different cases, the first slide can be $G , B$ or $R$.

First case:Consider the first tile as $Green$. Therefore we have $a(n-1)$ ways for the required condition.

Second case:Consider the first tile as $Blue$. Therefore we have $a(n-1)$ ways for the required condition.

Third case: Consider the first tile as $Red$. We now have three choices for the second tile, Therefore we have 3 sub-cases.
a) When second tile is $Green$ we have $RG$ and have $a(n-2)$ ways.

b) When second tile is $Blue$ we have $RB$ and have $a(n-2)$ ways.

c) When second tile is $RED$ we have $RR$ and we have to put a $Blue$ tile as the third tile because it is the required condition. So , we now have $RRB$ and $a(n-3)$ ways.

Therefore, the required relation will be :

$$a(n)= 2*a(n-1) + 2*a(n-2) + a(n-3) $$

We can similarly approach part d)